# Maxwell fit in 2 dimensions

Tags: fitting

The histogram below shows the 2D-velocities `v` of a micrometer sized particle in a plasma measured from image to image (60 Hz) over 33,33 sec.

I would like to fit this data by the 2D Maxwell-Boltzmann formula, to determine the temperature T:

```
p(v) = m/(k*T)*v*Exp(-m*v^2/(2*k*T)); 

with:

m = 5.99736*10^-13; (*particle mass in kg*)
k = 1.3806488*10^-23; (*Boltzmann constant in J/K*)
```

[image]

To solve that in Mathematica I used:

```
binSize = 0.000025; (*m/sec*)
hList = HistogramList[v, {binSize}];
```

Here are the 2d velocity data: http://pastebin.com/rtteUpk4

The result of this is:

```
vHist=hList[[1]]={0., 0.000025, 0.00005, 0.000075, 0.0001, 0.000125, 0.00015, 0.000175, 0.0002, 0.000225, 0.00025, 0.000275, 0.0003, 0.000325, 0.00035, 0.000375, 0.0004, 0.000425, 0.00045, 0.000475, 0.0005, 0.000525, 0.00055, 0.000575, 0.0006, 0.000625, 0.00065, 0.000675, 0.0007, 0.000725, 0.00075, 0.000775, 0.0008, 0.000825, 0.00085}
```

and

```
numHist=hList[[2]]={5, 16, 18, 36, 54, 59, 81, 107, 120, 110, 134, 135, 111, 97, 111, 115, 99, 95, 91, 81, 58, 58, 48, 41, 44, 24, 16, 18, 6, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1}
```

What do I have to correctly use as `data` (since `vHist` has 1 more element than numHist)? 
If they would have the same dimension I would try:

```
data=Transpose[{vHist,numHist}]
```

Now I thought to do the following as a test to plot the fit:

```
lenhthvHist = Length[vHist];
vHistHelp=vHist[[1 ;; lengthvHist - 1]];
data = Transpose[{vHistHelp, numHist}];
model = m/(k*T)*vHistHelp*Exp(-m*vHistHelp^2/(2*k*T));
fit = FindFit[data, model, {T}, vHistHelp];
modelf = Function[{t}, Evaluate[model /. fit]];
Plot[modelf[t], {t, 0, 0.0009}, Epilog -> Map[Point, data]]
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

How do I obtain the fitting curve?

Comment: I must leave in 5 min, but a few comments: 1. Wouldn't it be easier to determine the temperature from the mean velocity? 2. `{bins, counts} = HistogramList[...]` is much easier to write.  3. Element `-1` of a list is the same as element `Length[list] - 1`. 4. I didn't have time to understand your `model` fully, but it looks weird.  It should be a simple formula, why do you mix in the data?  5. Get the bin centres with `MovingAverage[bins,2]`.  Then you have the same number of values as in `counts`.

Comment: 6. It seems you are trying to fit a *probability density* to unnormalized *particle counts*.  That doesn't work.  Finally: since I wrote this in a hurry, there's probably something I misunderstood, for which I apologize in advance.  Hope some of the comments helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
numHist = numHist/Tr@numHist/vHist[[2]] // N;
data = Transpose[{MovingAverage[vHist, 2], numHist}];
m = 5.99736*10^-13;(*particle mass in kg*)
k = 1.3806488*10^-23;(*Boltzmann constant in J/K*)
model = m/(k*T)*v*Exp[-m*v^2/(2*k*T)];
fit = FindFit[data, model, {{T, 10}}, v]
modelf = Function[{v}, Evaluate[model /. fit]];
Plot[modelf[t], {t, 0, 0.0009}, Epilog -> Map[Point, data]]

(* {T -> 3315.85} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Probably you want your velocities in  m/s instead of in mm/s ... so to get your T result in reasonable units ...

Comment: Yes, the unit in the plot is m/sec. I put the wrong label and will correct it ... thanks ... and thanks a lot for the solution ...
Is it possible to use a second fit parameter (amplitude) to get the correct count values? 
What happens exactly in the first line: numHist = numHist/Tr@numHist/vHist[[2]] // N;
And what is the meaning of {{T,10}}?

Answer (score 12):

Because you are implying that you have a random sample of values of $v$ from a specified probability distribution, you should consider using maximum likelihood rather than least squares.  (In fact, I must comment that in this forum least squares seems to be often used for the estimation of parameters given a random sample which I would argue is almost never the way to do it.  At best it is inefficient and maybe the only use is to obtain starting values for an iterative maximum likelihood procedure but that's about it.  And there are other methods superior to least-squares.)

In this case there is an explicit maximum likelihood estimator for $T$.  If the observed velocities are store in a list named `v`, then the log of the likelihood function is

```
logL = n Log[m/(k T)] + Total@Log@v - (m v.v)/(2 k T)
```

The maximum likelihood estimator of T is That  ($\hat{T}$)

```
That = m v.v/(2 k n)
```

found with

```
That = T/.Solve[D[logL,T]==0,T][[1]]
```

The estimate of the asymptotic standard error is

```
sigma=FullSimplify[1/((-D[logL,{T,2}]/.T->That))^(1/2)]
```

or

```
sigma=1/(2 Sqrt[(k^2 n^3)/(m^2 (v.v)^2)])
```

**Update:**  Given the good suggestions by @rcollyer and @J.M. here is an expanded answer.

This distribution is named a Rayleigh distribution which is typically parameterized as

$$p(v)={{v}\over{\sigma^2}} e^{-v^2/(2 \sigma^2)}$$

where for this question $T=\sigma^2 m/k$.  We define some parameters so that a random sample of size $n$ can be taken:

```
m = 5.99736*10^-13;(*particle mass in kg*)
k = 1.3806488*10^-23;(*Boltzmann constant in J/K*)
T = 3316;
n = 1999;
```

Determine the parameter required by *Mathematica*'s `RayleighDistribution` and take a random sample:

```
σ = (k T/m)^(1/2)
(* 0.000276292 *)
v = RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[σ], n];
```

The maximum likelihood estimate of $T$ is found with

```
sol = FindDistributionParameters[v, RayleighDistribution[s]]
{s -> 0.000274438}
σhat = s /. sol
(* 0.000274438 *)
That = σhat^2  m/k
(* 3271.63 *)
```

The direct formula for $\hat T$ is

```
That = m v.v/(2 k n)
(* 3271.63 *)
```

One shortcoming of `FindDistributionParameters` is that no estimates of standard errors seem to be available.  For this maximum likelihood estimator there is a closed-form for the estimate of the asymptotic standard error:

```
m v.v/(2 k n^(3/2))
(* 73.1741 *)
```

One can bin the values to create a histogram of the data but the estimation should be performed with the raw data.  And with this much data using `SmoothKernelDistribution` should be used instead of `Histogram`.  Using the bins and counts from above we can approximate the maximum likelihood estimate:

```
counts = {5, 16, 18, 36, 54, 59, 81, 107, 120, 110, 134, 135, 111, 97,
    111, 115, 99, 95, 91, 81, 58, 58, 48, 41, 44, 24, 16, 18, 6, 6, 2,
    1, 1, 1};

vHist = {0., 0.000025, 0.00005, 0.000075, 0.0001, 0.000125, 0.00015, 
   0.000175, 0.0002, 0.000225, 0.00025, 0.000275, 0.0003, 0.000325, 
   0.00035, 0.000375, 0.0004, 0.000425, 0.00045, 0.000475, 0.0005, 
   0.000525, 0.00055, 0.000575, 0.0006, 0.000625, 0.00065, 0.000675, 
   0.0007, 0.000725, 0.00075, 0.000775, 0.0008, 0.000825, 0.00085};

midPoints = Table[(vHist[[i]] + vHist[[i + 1]])/2, {i, Length[counts]}];

That = m counts.(midPoints^2) /(2 k Total[counts])
(* 3043.82 *)
sigma = m counts.(midPoints^2)/(2 k Total[counts]^(3/2))
(* 68.0789 *)
```

A plot of the fit is shown below:

```
  Show[ListPlot[Flatten[Table[{{vHist[[i]], 0}, {vHist[[i]], 
      counts[[i]]/0.049975}, {vHist[[i + 1]], 
      counts[[i]]/0.049975}, {vHist[[i + 1]], 0}}, {i, 
     Length[counts]}], 1], Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 3000}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{Style["Probability density", Large, Bold, Black], 
     ""}, {"", ""}}],
 Plot[(m/(k That)) vv Exp[-m vv^2/(2 k That)], {vv, 0, 0.001}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Histogram and fit]

If only binned data is available, a better approach would be to used the censored likelihood approach.  And after all of this goodness-of-fit should be examined but I've run out of time for now.

**Second update**

The raw data has been made available and below is the fit using that data.  The 1,999 data points have been assigned to the variable named `v`.

```
(* Set constants and Rayleigh distribution parameter *)
m = 5.99736*10^-13;(*particle mass in kg*)
k = QuantityMagnitude[
  UnitConvert[
   Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"]]];(*Boltzmann constant in J/K*)
n = Length[v];
sigma = (k T/m)^(1/2);

(* Find maximum likelihood estimate of T *)
sol = FindDistributionParameters[v, RayleighDistribution[s]];
sigmahat = s /. sol
(* 0.00026481579806363645 *)
That = sigmahat^2 m/k
(* 3046.2439475575343 *)
(* As a check using the closed-form maximum likelihood solution *)
That = m v.v/(2 k n)
(* 3046.2439475575347 *)

(* Standard error of That *)
seT = m v.v/(2 k n^(3/2))
(* 68.13312083776144` *)

(* Approximate 95% confidence interval for T *)
{That - 1.96 seT, That + 1.96 seT}
(* {2912.7030307155223`,3179.784864399547`} *)
```

A plot of the results:

```
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[v];
Show[Histogram[v, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[d, v], {v, 0, 0.00085}],
 Plot[PDF[RayleighDistribution[sigmahat], v], {v, 0, 0.00085}, PlotStyle -> Red], ImageSize -> Large]
DistributionFitTest[v, RayleighDistribution[sigmahat]]
```

With the `SmoothKernelDistribution` in gray/blue and the maximum likelihood fit in red:

[image]

It certainly does not look like a perfect fit.  Using `DistributionFitTest` results in a very, very small P-value suggesting a lack of fit:

```
DistributionFitTest[v, RayleighDistribution[sigmahat]]
(* 8.790774019828973`*^-8 *)
```

Part of the problem using P-values is that small and practically inconsequential differences can become "statistically significant" with large sample sizes.  So an examination of the data is order.  Plotting the raw data in sequence results in a very non-random arrangement of values in time order.  This lack of expected randomness is critical because the rationale for being able to estimate $T$ relies on random and independent samples from the Rayleigh distribution.

Here we see high autocorrelation

```
tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[v]["BestFit"]
(* ARProcess[0.00003833580283247393`,0.5734763681300956`,0.4570403165209849`,
0.08967306679823858`,-0.018997998762076446`,-0.12439400350041019`,
-0.08876573889266684`},3.3484025317002574`*^-9] *)
```

and maybe some periodicity as evidenced by showing the first 200 data points:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{i, v[[i]]}, {i, 1, 200}], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Periodicity]

The periodicity is even more evident in the complete series:

[image: Periodicity in complete series]

It might be best to address this issue at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.  One possibility is to only use every 25th sample point as distasteful as that sounds.  (But the assumptions should still be examined even after doing that.)

Comment: I have some suggestions on your code. `Log` is listable, so use `Total@Log[v]` instead of an explicit `Sum`. Similarly, `v.v` or `Total[v^2]` for the sum of squares. This enables _Mathematica_ to invoke the vector engine which will vastly speed up your code.

Comment: Also, your variable names are inconsistent. I presume `T` is the same as `t` in `logL`?

Comment: @rcollyer.  Thanks!  I'll update the answer with those suggestions.  (Such suggestions is why I really like this forum.)

Comment: @rcollyer.  Yes, I had to jump from one computer to another and didn't make all of the changes.  I started out with all lower-case and then decided to include a capital T but then didn't change all of the occurrences.  I will change that.

Comment: BTW: `RayleighDistribution[]` is built-in. This can now be used with `FindDistributionParameters[]` to perform maximum likelihood fitting.

Comment: @J.M.  Good suggestion.  When I get off work today I'll add that into the answer along with some suggestions about "goodness of fit" (or lack thereof).

Comment: A few additional notes: 1. the Boltzmann constant is known to *Mathematica*: `QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"]]]`. 2. If a goodness-of-fit is also needed, then one uses `DistributionFitTest[]` for that.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks.  But I'm going to mildly disagree because of some nitpicky things about DistributionFitTest.  (1) the raw data is needed, (2) when the raw data is available, DistributionFitTest will test whether the data fits a specified distribution rather than a distribution with parameters fitted with the data being examined, and (3) such tests are based on statistical significance rather than any practical significance so with a large enough sample size minor imperfections will result in statistical significance.  Having said all of that, such a test should still be examined.

Comment: 1. Yes, the OP really should have provided (a subset of) the raw data. 2. Actually, `DistributionFitTest[]` is exactly the function needed (in much the same way `LinearModelFit[]` is an augmented version of `FindFit[]`). As an example: `hd = DistributionFitTest[data, RayleighDistribution[s], "HypothesisTestData"]; hd["FittedDistributionParameters"]`. 3. Yes, that's the *caveat emptor* part of such tests; I won't dispute you there. :)

Comment: I stand corrected about the capabilities of `DistributionFitTest`.

Comment: Here are the 2d velocity data: http://pastebin.com/rtteUpk4

Comment: Nicely done; it's too bad I can't upvote again.